# Cannot compile program on Ubuntu that uses libmcrypt

Tags: c, compiler-errors, mcrypt

I created a C program that uses *libmcrypt*. I compiled it for many times in a CentOS machine, but now, trying to do the same thing in Ubuntu, I get this:

```
/tmp/ccM2ugbq.o: In function `encrypt': 
util.c:(.text+0xa1): undefined reference to `mcrypt_module_open'
util.c:(.text+0xc6): undefined reference to `mcrypt_enc_get_iv_size'
util.c:(.text+0x134): undefined reference to `mcrypt_generic_init'
util.c:(.text+0x1dc): undefined reference to `mcrypt_generic'
util.c:(.text+0x1fa): undefined reference to `mcrypt_module_close'
/tmp/ccM2ugbq.o: In function `decrypt':
util.c:(.text+0x288): undefined reference to `mcrypt_module_open'
util.c:(.text+0x296): undefined reference to `mcrypt_enc_get_iv_size'
util.c:(.text+0x304): undefined reference to `mcrypt_generic_init'
util.c:(.text+0x375): undefined reference to `mdecrypt_generic'
util.c:(.text+0x380): undefined reference to `mcrypt_module_close'
```

, although I have installed *libmcrypt* and have spacified the flags properly when compile (*-I/usr/include -L/usr/lib -lmcrypt*)

Can anyone guide me on how to get the compilation work  properly with *libmcrypt*?

---

EDIT: man pages says: *Compile as "cc prog.c -lmcrypt", or "cc prog.c -lmcrypt -lltdl" depending on your  installation.*
I also installed *libltdl-dev*, but it does not work.

---

EDIT 1:
System information:
version (running `uname -r`):

> 3.5.0-25-generic

release (running `lsb_release -a`):

> No LSB modules are available.
>
> Distributor ID:   Ubuntu
>
> Description:  Ubuntu 12.10
>
> Release:  12.10
>
> Codename: quantal

---

EDIT 2:

Because @teppic requested me to show the compile command, I solved my issue, but I need some explanations. Bellow I'll detail the topic:

the command that I used and failed:

> cc -Wall -I../path/to/include -lmcrypt ./a_file.c ./some/other/file.c ./some/other/files.c ./main/file.c  -I/some/include/path -lother_lib -o ./bin/out

After that, I only put the `-lmcrypt` at the end of command and deleted it from the first place, and it worked.
In my initial question, I told you that I did compile it before in CentOS and everything worked fine. That's true, even if in CentOS the compile command were the former one (probably some files differ in order or some libraries).

Can anybody explain me how the flags order influences the compilation success or failure?

Comment: did you install `libmcrypt-dev`?

Comment: @WillPalmer yes, I also installed *libltdl-dev* and included it, but the same behaviour.

Comment: can you give exact OS info?

Comment: What's the exact command you're using to compile?

Comment: @teppic see my EDIT 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general you should put the library dependency *after* the source file that references it in the command line. In older versions of gcc, this wasn't always the case.

Answer (score 1):

1) Try installing libmrypt-dev
2) Locate the path of libmcrypt using "locate" command
3) If not in standard library path, try adding the path to LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable
4) If nothing helps try installing again using "yum install mcrypt-devel"

Comment: what's libwock32? I can't find such a library.